# How to change navbar to match colour of app?

Tags: android

Can anyone kindly share how to change the colour of virtual navbar (the one with back, home and menu icon) for android 5.0 and above such that is seen in gmail and hangouts app?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your styles.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    ...
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/MyColor</item>
    ...

</style>
```

You can find out more about changing the color theme in 5.0 in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)